# Disallow any internet connection

Tags: linux, network-interface, internet, acl, nas

*Story, you may skip.*

> Recently Western Digital has announced that some of older NAS devices
> are in grave danger due to a exploit that makes it possible to factory
> reset devices. Hundreds of NAS devices got wiped. WD suggested simply
> "unplugging" the device. Even though i disabled remote access from it's dashboard, it still can communicate with internet to send some sort of email notification on reset etc. I even disabled UPnP on my router. But it still can communicate with outer world.

I SSH'd to my NAS (Network Attached Storage) to disable it from accessing internet and getting accessed by internet. My initial attempt was to mess with the contents of **/etc/network/interfaces** but couldn't do it properly. Later i changed it back to default. Here's the content of /etc/network/interfaces: (Currently connected to a PC through RJ-45)

```
# Configure Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0  inet dhcp
allow-hotplug eth0
```

uname -a output of the NAS:

```
Linux Stronghold 2.6.32.11-svn70860 #1 Thu May 17 13:32:51 PDT 2012 ppc GNU/Linux
```

Later i thought i could use UFW to disallow anything outside local. But apparently UFW is not installed. I can't connect NAS to internet since there is a great risk of it getting wiped. Therefore i can't install any external packages.

**TL;DR**

How can i disable external connections (internet) outside LAN on Linux without installing any external packages such as UFW.

Comment: I suggest looking through the manual and finding out how to filter network connections. Even though UFW isn't installed, there's probably a way. You can find it online if you don't have a physical copy of it.

Comment: But it's not meant to be used by connecting it directly to a PC. It's meant to be connected to a router. But as soon as i connect it to a router it just connects to some endpoint to send email notification.

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: Wats wrong with `iptables` ? Can you use it?

Comment: Offhand, what options have you considered and researched? Is placing the NAS on an isolated VLAN an option? Using a reverse proxy/gatekeeper (similar to the way websites may combine several web servers, like web1.domain.com, web2.domain.com, etc, in to one single logical server at www.domain.com)? Et cetera. As it is, your question may be too general or broad. Narrow it and be more specific.

Comment: You could configure your DHCP server to not publish a default gateway for the specific setting of the NAS server: no gateway no internet.

Comment: Static IP on the device. No default route

Comment: Filter out *all* traffic to/from the NAS at your router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `iptables` :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s LAN_NET/LAN_MASK -j ACCEPT
```

So if your lan is at : `192.168.1.0` and you have a `/24` netmask:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

---

Delete `default route`:

if you have `iproute2` package functionality, use the `ip` command:

```
ip route del default
```

Or use the old interface `route` for doing the same job.

Comment: I used something that is inspired from your answer: " sudo route del default gw 192.168.1.1" whereas 192.168.1.1 is my gateway.